# MySQL display entire group, sort alphabetically within group

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 

FROM vendors_parts INNER JOIN 

vendors ON vendors_parts.vendor = vendors.vendor_id

WHERE (vendors_parts.vendor = @vendor_id) AND (vendors_parts.active = @active) OR

(vendors_parts.vendor = @vendor_id) AND (vendors_parts.active = @inactive)

ORDER BY vendors_parts.old_id, vendors_parts.vendor_part, date_start DESC, vendors_parts.active DESC
```

Which returns data in the following format:

```
vendor_part      active       old_id
b                1            1
a                0            1
a                0            1
b                0            1
x                1            3
z                1            5
c                1            20
c                0            20
```

My question is how do I keep the old_id together while sorting the vendor_part ascending and active descending? The output I would like is:

```
vendor_part      active       old_id
b                1            1
a                0            1
a                0            1
b                0            1
c                1            20
c                0            20
x                1            3
z                1            5
```

I've also tried a sub query that groups on old_id, but this limits me to only one unique old_id:

```
SELECT *

FROM 
     (
     SELECT * FROM vendors_parts INNER JOIN vendors ON vendors_parts.vendor = vendors.vendor_id
     WHERE (vendors_parts.vendor = @vendor_id) AND (vendors_parts.active = @active) OR (vendors_parts.vendor = @vendor_id) AND (vendors_parts.active = @inactive)
     GROUP BY vendors_parts.old_id
     ) temp_table
ORDER BY vendor_part
```

How do I show all of the old_ids grouped together, and sorted alphabetically by vendor_part within their respective groups?

thank you

Comment: Ive added my schema and some sample data to sqlfidle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd612/1

Comment: That's great to have put a sqlfiddle, but you should probably have narrow down your use case. Perhaps limiting yourself to the example you gave in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible answer. Please note in this answer the table `tbl` is a placeholder for your actual (rather complex) query (I dislike resorting on that but you might have to use a temporary table to keep the query syntax manageable):

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM tbl 
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(vendor_part) as mvp, old_id FROM tbl GROUP BY old_id) as driver
  USING (old_id)
  ORDER BY driver.mvp, tbl.old_id, active DESC, tbl.vendor_part
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c53a9/4 for the live demo. As you will see, using the example you gave in your question, it produces the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Sylvain for your help. It seems the USING command is what I was missing in conjunction with a temporary table. I do have one question about the results.. check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f8df/1 to see how I've modified your answer. Do you see how it isn't always alphabetical for vendor_part?

2
2
new name
3... etc

Comment: @chureema All things being equal, if you want the row to be sorted by `vendor_part` you just have to add that to the `ORDER BY` clause. I edited man answer accordingly. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f8df/7